# Incorrect syntax near data types

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
CREATE TABLE KCustomer(CUS_CODE int,CUS_LNAME varchar(50),CUS_FNAME varchar(50),CUS_INITIAL varchar(50),CUS_RENEW_DATE varchar(50),AGENT_CODE int,)
INSERT INTO KCustomer VALUES(10010, 'Ramas', 'Alfred', 'A', 05-'April'-2018, 502)
```

Incorrect syntax near data types.

Comment: Remove the last comma in the create statement. Use A date type for your date column and insert the date in the correct format yyyy-mm-dd

Answer (score 0):

To extend Jürgen's comment:

```sql
CREATE TABLE KCustomer
(CUS_CODE int, CUS_LNAME varchar(50), CUS_FNAME varchar(50), CUS_INITIAL varchar(50), CUS_RENEW_DATE DateTime, AGENT_CODE int)

INSERT INTO KCustomer 
VALUES(10010, 'Ramas', 'Alfred', 'A', #2018-04-05#, 502)
```